# Is there a way to read a file from where I left off in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tomcat9

I'm trying to read a file in Python, close it and then read it again from the point where I stopped reading it.

Real problem: I'm trying to process a Tomcat log file which is updated every hour. So when I read it from Python end, I get duplicate (old) logs as well as the new ones.

Edit: Is there an efficient way to read the new logs from the common file?

Comment: Why do you need to close it?

Comment: you can save the amount of lines you read and skip those the next time

Comment: That is beacuse I don't want to keep it open while tomcat updates it.

Comment: Is this actually worth optimizing? This sounds like it miiight be a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See where you are: `offset = f.tell()`

Go back to where you were: `f.seek(offset)`

[Relevant point in tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pygtail](https://pypi.org/project/pygtail/) for this, it reads the log file lines that have not been read means it will start from the point where it was last processed or where it was stopped

```
from pygtail import Pygtail
for line in Pygtail("path to your log file"):
    '''
    the process which you want to do
    '''
```

Answer (score 1):

- Before closing the file save the line number from which you left off
- Use linecache module for getting that line as current line
- Here some code you can use

# import linecache module

import linecache

# define the name of the file to read from

filename = "test.txt"

# define line_number

line_number = 3

# retrieve specific line

line = linecache.getline(filename, line_number)

print ("line %i of %s:" % (line_number, filename))

print (line)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option, make the Tomcat logs rotate every one hour. You just need to read the unread file in logs directory in that case.